# Error Converting Image Python with numpy no attribute 'convert'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello guys I just wanna ask, yesterday I got no problem with this code, and suddenly today I reopen my code and this happen.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image

image = plt.imread('201030094143-stock-rhodesian-ridgeback-exlarge-169.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)

image_c = image.convert('L') 
plt.imshow(image_c)
```

and the notification error is

```
1 #Melakukan converting image menggunakan image convert
----> 2 image_c = image.convert('L')
      3 plt.imshow(image_c)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'convert'
```

Comment: Always post full error tracebacks!

Comment: here, i already updated with the full error tracebacks